# Error en staticinjectorerror(appmodule) Angular 5

Tags: angular

Hola estoy intentando añadir unas directivas a un formulario para poder enviarlos, pero cuando coloco la directiva `[(ngModel)]="tareaService.TareaSeleccionada.nombre"` me salta este error.

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TareaService -> AngularFireDatabase]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TareaService -> AngularFireDatabase]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1062)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1141)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
    at _createClass (core.js:8421)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8393)
```

El objeto **"tareaService"** lo declaré en el componente y lo importé en el `app.module.ts` así que no habría problema por ese lado, es curioso  también porque aunque borre el formulario el error sigue, así que el error no es en el formulario sino que puede ser en el componente o el servicio, aquí los añado:

**SERVICIO**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

// Clase
import { Tarea } from '../clases/tarea';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TareaService {

  ListaTareas: AngularFireList <any>;
  TareaSeleccionada:Tarea= new Tarea();
  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ListarTareas(){
    return this.ListaTareas=this.firebase.list('tareitas');
  }

  InsertarTarea(tarea:Tarea){
    this.ListaTareas.push({
      nombre:tarea.nombre
    })
  }

  ActualizarTarea(tarea:Tarea){
    this.ListaTareas.update(tarea.$key,{
      nombre:tarea.nombre
    })
  }

  EliminarTarea($key: string){
    this.ListaTareas.remove($key);
  }
}
```

**COMPONENTE**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
// Servicios
import { TareaService } from '../../../servicios/tarea.service';
import { Tarea } from '../../../clases/tarea';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tarea',
  templateUrl: './tarea.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tarea.component.css']
})
export class TareaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tarea: TareaService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // reiniciarFormuario(formulario: NgForm){
  //   if(formulario!=null){
  //     formulario.reset();
  //     this.tareaService.TareaSeleccionada=new Tarea();
  //   }
  // }

}
```

Comment: Hola, aclara tu problema específico y añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas. Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página 
 y realiza el [tour o recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee sobre [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya lo hice, puedes volver a leer

Comment: Entonces, tu error solo surge cuando haces uso de la directiva de `[(ngModel)]="tareaService.TareaSeleccionada.nombre"` ?

Answer (score 0):

No es un problema de tu directiva. El error real es:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!

Lo que significa que **no** estás inicializando `AngularFire2` y `AngularFireDatabase` de la manera correcta.

[Las instrucciones de configuración (en inglés)](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md) indican que debes ingresar en tu [`AppModule` las configuraciones de tu proyecto de Firebase](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md#5-setup-ngmodule-for-the-angularfiremodule), además de agregar el `AngularFireDatabaseModule`. Te quedaría algo como:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase) // en donde estan tus llaves de firebase
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    // Otros modulos que necesités...
    // AngularFireAuthModule,
    // el resto de tu AppModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

De ésta manera tu `TareaService` tendrá acceso al provider de `AngularFireDatabase`.